# How to add buttons in alternate listitem in listview?

Tags: android, listview

I am developing one application where I am using `ListView` now what i am trying is I want to add one `Button` in every alternate **listitem**,

Something like this

**listitem1**
**Button**  **listitem2**
**listitem3**
**Button** **listitem4**

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:background="@drawable/heads">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/rl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                       android:text="abd"
                android:id="@+id/txt_allproductsname"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="abddd"
                android:id="@+id/txt_allproductsquty"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btntest"
        android:text="test"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Code

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_homefrags, null);
        // holder.propic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.propicaccept);
        holder.txtproname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_allproductsquty);
        // holder.txtproid = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtproidacptedlist);
        holder.txtprofilecast = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_allproductsname);

        holder.testbtn=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btntest);
        // holder.txtprofileage = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtprofileageacptedlist);
        // holder.txtprofileplace = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtprofileplaceacptedlist);


        if (position % 1 == 0) {
            holder.testbtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.testbtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this

As you are writing the **showing/hiding** code in

```
if(convertView==null){
 // only executes if convertview is null
}else{
  // get cached element
}
```

so move **showing/hiding** logic after `else`

```
@Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_homefrags, null);
               // holder.propic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.propicaccept);
                holder.txtproname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_allproductsquty);
               // holder.txtproid = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtproidacptedlist);
                holder.txtprofilecast = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_allproductsname);

                holder.testbtn=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btntest);
               // holder.txtprofileage = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtprofileageacptedlist);
               // holder.txtprofileplace = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtprofileplaceacptedlist);




                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

                if (position % 2 == 0) {

                    holder.testbtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                } else {
                    holder.testbtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
```

Comment: as viewholder pattern is used for caching purpose  see this link http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html

Comment: can you tell http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847086/how-to-attach-jpg-or-png-file-to-gmail-or-facebook

Answer (score 2):

`position % 1` is *always* 0. You should use `position % 2 == 1` to get the result you describe.

The '%' in Java represents a modulo operation. The modulo operation returns the fraction of an integer division which could not be divided. For example, if you divide 10 by 5 you get 2 with a rest of 0. But when you would divide 13 by 5 you would get 2 with a rest of 3, hence `12%5` would return 3

Comment: not working..it shows..buton listitem1 then listitem2 then listite3..so on

Comment: tell me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847086/how-to-attach-jpg-or-png-file-to-gmail-or-facebook

Answer (score 1):

You can add button to the item layout of the `ListView` and set the visiblity of the adapters `getView` method. You need to go for the custom adapter for this type of `ListView`.

You need to put the below line of code

```
if (position % 2 == 0) {
    holder.testbtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    holder.testbtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

before the `return` statement.

Comment: tell me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847086/how-to-attach-jpg-or-png-file-to-gmail-or-facebook