# How to change color of hamburger icon in material design navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, user-interface, material-design, navigation-drawer

I am following this example

http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/

and in this example it is showing hamburger icon white,i want to customize it and make it black,but i am not able to find anything to how to change it,can any one tell how to customize it?

Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.androidhive.materialdesign" >


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

style

```
<resources>

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">

    </style>

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/hamburger</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

    private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
        drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

        // display the first navigation drawer view on app launch
        displayView(0);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        if(id == R.id.action_search){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Search action is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
        displayView(position);
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_home);
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new FriendsFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_friends);
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new MessagesFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_messages);
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new ContactUsFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_contactus);
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = new AboutUsFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_aboutus);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            // set the toolbar title
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        }
    }
```

Comment: just use the following line        <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/icon_top_menu
            </item> in style.xml theme.,,replace    icon_top_menu with custom drawable

Comment: i add this  <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/icon_top_menu </item>..now can you tell what to do..

Comment: add another image in your drawable with desired color burger menu icon and replace icon_top_menu  with that in above

Comment: icon_top_menu should be image right?

Comment: i added one image         <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/hamburger</item>
its stil showing white image

Comment: post your manifest and style.xml

Answer (score 254, accepted):

To change color of hamburger icon you have to open "style.xml" class, then try this code:

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">

</style>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

So check `<item name="color">@android:color/black</item>` line. Just change your desired color here.

Comment: anyway you can check this https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer link. It have good tutorial.

Comment: so write above code in your MainActivity , it will work.

Comment: but its not allowing for download

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85382/discussion-between-roman-and-anand-singh).

Comment: Good answer. Would you happen to know how to change the colour of the icon for selected activities instead?

Comment: Any way to set DrawerArrowStyle to specific toolbars ? And what's the default value of it?

Comment: it only worked for me programmatically - actionBarDrawerToggle.drawerArrowDrawable.color = Color.WHITE

Answer (score 70):

do it programmatically add this line

```
actionBarDrawerToggle.getDrawerArrowDrawable().setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

Comment: but how do we get a reference to actionBarDrawerToggle? (running your suggested code will return null because we don't a reference to the actionBarDrawerToggle)

Comment: Look no further, Sai Gopi N answered the question correctly. To answer Daron, you have to make an instance in your main activity. ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);

Answer (score 17):

1.In Color.xml.`<color name="hamburgerBlack">#000000</color>`

2.In style.xml.

```
<style name="DrawerIcon" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="color">@color/hamburgerBlack</item>
    </style>
```

3. Then your main theme class(File name style.xml).I have “AppTheme”.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
         <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerIcon</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Please provide full step to apply icon in kotlin

Answer (score 14):

Overriding colorControlNormal also works.

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
```

Answer (score 13):

yourProject/res/values/styles.xml

in the styles.xml add:

```
<style name="BaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item> 
</style>
```

Comment: only for API 20 and up

Answer (score 12):

For that you can proceed as follows:

```java
protected ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

drawerToggle.getDrawerArrowDrawable().setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
```

Comment: @Gratien Asimbahwe this code you posted will crash because there is no reference to drawerToggle....how do we get a reference?

Answer (score 2):

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorTransparent"
```

> remove themes too

```
    android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoActionBar.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      ***
```

> remove this

***  app:popupTheme="@style/AppThemeNoActionBar.PopupOverlay">

```
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

finally add this

```
 <style name="AppThemeNoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

> To your main heme

```
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorRedTitle</item>

    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works fine when you set app:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"

Comment: Or if you match your android manifest theme name to the style name in your styles.xml.

Answer (score 0):

After a struggle of 2 hours , this post helped me .
In Androidhive material example, change primary color to another for getting new actionbar color.
this below code is for getting arrow mark on action bar and making custom text.
Finally i understood that, arrow icon will be in appcompat resource files but hamburger icon not present in resources. if it is present we can change it at runtime

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
        upArrow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.black), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"black\">" + "All Addresses" + "</font>"));
        getSupportActionBar().show();
```

for changing the home button, i followed @anandsingh answer.

Comment: That's is a pretty hacky and hard to maintain way.. I'd say it would be better not to do anything than follow this. That could help to get a sample working for a demo though.

Comment: @Tarun Voora - this might be just what i am looking for...i am looking for a way to change it using code...i will look into this within the next couple of days...thanks in advance!... i am looking for the hamburger menu icon though...but this may point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
//----------your own toolbar-----------------------------

            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:background="@color/blue"
                >
                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    //-----------Main activity xml, add your own toolbar-----------------------------------------------
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.v1technologies.sgcarel.FrameActivity">
        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            />
        <FrameLayout
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:id="@+id/frame_frame_activity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>


        //----  In your activity-----------------------

                   toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);       
                    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            //===========================================================================

             @Override
                public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

                    int color = Color.parseColor("#334412");
                    final PorterDuffColorFilter colorFilter = new PorterDuffColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

                    for (int i = 0; i < toolbar.getChildCount(); i++) {
                        final View v = toolbar.getChildAt(i);

                        if (v instanceof ImageButton) {
                            ((ImageButton) v).setColorFilter(colorFilter);
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  val drawerToggle = DrawerArrowDrawable(this)
    drawerToggle.color = ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.white)
    (actionBarDrawerToggle as ActionBarDrawerToggle).drawerArrowDrawable = drawerToggle
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change the color just to your navigation drawer icon, try this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    app:itemIconTint="@color/thecolorthatyouwant"
 />
```

straight in your activity_drawer.xml

Answer (score -1):

The hamburger icon is controlled by your action `ActionBarDrawerToggle` class.
If you are using the android compat libraries which is a must as at now. You can change the color like this:

```
    toggle?.drawerArrowDrawable?.color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary)
```

Comment: this code you posted will crash because there is no reference to drawerToggle....how do we get a reference?