# Unable to change the color of hamburger icon in Android Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have created a navigation drawer which has hamburger/back icon animation in the actionbar. The only problem is that I am unable to change the color of the hamburger icon to white. I followed [How to style the DrawerArrowToggle from Android appcompat v7 21 library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26439572/how-to-style-the-drawerarrowtoggle-from-android-appcompat-v7-21-library) and [How to change color of hamburger icon in material design navigation drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870132/how-to-change-color-of-hamburger-icon-in-material-design-navigation-drawer).

My code:

```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/appPrimaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlowIcon</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="spinBars">true</item>
        <item name="color">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

However, this does not seem to work. Any ideas why?

Comment: Did you try `@android:color/white`?

Comment: Yes, tried that as well. No luck!

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28631979/1841194

Comment: Great! That worked. Thanks! :)

Comment: You also have another option! Using your own icons.