# Change the color of default back arrow provided by action bar

Tags: android, colors, android-actionbar

I am setting the back arrow of the action bar and changing its color like so:

```
final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_navigation_arrow_back);
upArrow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
```

And as you can see, I am changing the color of the arrow in this line because the default returned arrow is gray, here:

```
upArrow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

And the color is changing but the problem that it is a bit transparent although the color `white` that I am providing has the following hex code `#FFFFFFFF`.

Here are two images that will make my point clear.

This is how it looks:

[image: This is how it looks]

While the color should like this other component:

[image]

And I tried all the options that are under `PorterDuff.Mode.XXXX` but none worked.

Comment: **Check out this** [Already Have Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870132/how-to-change-color-of-hamburger-icon-in-material-design-navigation-drawer)

Comment: @Abhishek no this is not the same issue, because am not asking how to change the color of the item but instead am asking why the color filtering is not giving the required result

Answer (score 2):

plz change in your style.xml

```
    <style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="Custom.Base">

   </style>

<style name="Custom.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: this is not my question

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Toolbar then 
add item in your AppTheme.

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
```

But Make sure that you don´t have another theme defined in your Toolbar element on your layout.

Comment: i am using custom toolbar

Comment: Thanks. Worked fine