# Where This Navigation Icon Stored?

Tags: android

I just created a new project in Android Studio and I choose `Navigation Drawer Activity`.

After I made few changes, I realized that I need to change this icon color into dark grey. because the action bar background will be white.

[image]

where this icon png file stored? thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change color of hamburger icon in material design navigation drawer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870132/how-to-change-color-of-hamburger-icon-in-material-design-navigation-drawer)

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/42293785/4571925

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the color of the icon by applying custom theme for your toolbar.You can use the below for reference

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base"/>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/IconStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="IconStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@color/your_desired_color</item>
</style>
```

Comment: what is the difference between your answer and mine?

Comment: @AdityaVyas-Lakhan I was also posting the answer at that time. It is just that you submitted it earlier

Comment: @AnkushBist Try to answer in a better way

Comment: i was just kidding. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change icon color,you need to change in style.xml

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">

</style>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/red</item>
</style>
```

Java

```
 Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    mToolbar.setTitle("title");
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you create new project and choose NavigationDrawerActivity. You can change icon drawer on NavigationDrawerFragment.class at line   R.drawable.ic_drawer,

```
public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
    mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to call this for changing color of this navigation icon.

```
toolbar.getNavigationIcon().setColorFilter(Color.YourColor, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use above solution , but still if you want icons you can get it over here  https://material.io/icons/#ic_menu , download the size and few colour you want

generally all the inbuilt icons will be in  SDK folder

```
\sdk\platforms\android-23\data\res\drawable
```