# Change Hamburger/backarrow toolbar color Android

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, navigation-drawer

I want to change the color of my hamburger/backarrow in the toolbar from colorPrimaryDark to white.

In my style.xml file I have 2 themes:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>


<!-- Toolbar theme. -->
<style name="toolbar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

and this is my toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/toolbar"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
  android:elevation="4dp"
  android:theme="@style/toolbar">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I tried with several methods and the only one that works is move `<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>` from toolbar theme to base application theme.

That's not ok for me because setting textColorSecondary to white in base theme change other components color too. 
I want to set it only for my toolbar. But it does not work even though I have`<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>` and set my toolbar style into the toolbar.xml using `"android:theme="@style/toolbar"`

[image]

[image]

the strange thing is that the other theme colors are applied properly.

where am I wrong?

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870132/how-to-change-color-of-hamburger-icon-in-material-design-navigation-drawer)?

Comment: yes, but it change only the color of the hamburger icon not both, why?

Answer (score 2):

Work around: 
(but i think it isn't an elegant solution)

i set the default arrow icon with this:

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material);
```

and change hamburger color with this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/white</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style> 

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```