# How to change icon color menu in AppBar ANDROID

Tags: android

I am creating an android application using "Navigation Drawer Activity" template. When the application is created, by default, the icon color menu is white. And my aim is to change this icon color menu.
Not only, by reading blogs and forum to solve it, but also, by searching documentation in the net, I can't still achieve this.
Could anyone help me?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6xWr.png)

Comment: This question should be closed. Please checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870132/how-to-change-color-of-hamburger-icon-in-material-design-navigation-drawer

Comment: Than you very much @Abhisheck, it works like a charm!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey there you can do this :-

- Add custom style in your styles.xml

  ```
  <style name="NavDrawerIcon" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
      <item name="color">@android:color/black</item>
  </style>
  ```
- Then in your app theme add this line :-

  `<item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/NavDrawerIcon</item>`

This will change your icon color to Black.

Comment: Thank you very much @App Dev, it works too!!

Comment: @zayann Do mark this answer as accepted and up vote it if it did help you.

Comment: Another question to this please, how to change the color of the title placed in the AppBar when we click an item from the drawerNavigation, like Home for example

Comment: you can add this line of code in your app theme :- 
`<item name="titleTextColor">@android:color/black</item>`
This will change the titlt "Home" color to black. 

Do upvote this answer so that others can find easily.

Comment: Very good, thanks again @App Dev!