# how to change the color of the hamburger icon in the navigation view in android studio

Tags: java, android

I created a navigation drawer and now I want to change the color of the hamburger icon of the navigation drawer to Gold.
how to change the color of the hamburger icon of the navigation drawer and also the text to gold
here is my code also there is a photo of how it current look like

```
package com.example.entertainmentlab;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    protected ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.

        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_trending, R.id.nav_audio, R.id.nav_videos)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

        final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nav);
        upArrow.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
```

[image: Navigation image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change color of hamburger icon in material design navigation drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870132/how-to-change-color-of-hamburger-icon-in-material-design-navigation-drawer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to figure out a way to change the hamburger icon color with this code  I wrote this code in my style.xml

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerIcon</item>
        <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonOverflow</item>

    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>


    <style name="MyActionButtonOverflow" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton.Overflow">
        <item name="color">#ffd700</item>
    </style>
    <style name="DrawerIcon" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="color">#ffd700</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


</resources>
```

[image: result]

Now add the below code to your Navigation view java activity which in my case is the HomeActivity

```
toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorelabGold));
```

**Now you get**
[image: result three]